# I added a HSTS header to my nginx.conf now it wont start up

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu, nginx, webserver

I added a HSTS header to my nginx.conf now it wont start up. I removed it and then tried restarting, no luck.

**systemctl status nginx.service**

```
 nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
    Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/nginx.service.d
             └─limits.conf
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2021-09-28 14:43:48 UTC; 13min ago
    Process: 65187 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Sep 28 14:43:48 localhost systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Sep 28 14:43:48 localhost nginx[65187]: nginx: [warn] "ssl_stapling" ignored, issuer certificate not found for certificate "/var/www/22222/cert/22222.crt"
Sep 28 14:43:48 localhost nginx[65187]: nginx: [emerg] "rewrite" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:109
Sep 28 14:43:48 localhost nginx[65187]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
Sep 28 14:43:48 localhost systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 28 14:43:48 localhost systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 28 14:43:48 localhost systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
```

(Ubuntu 20.04)

I don't have a backup - is there anyway for me to fix this with out losing my WordPress site?

Comment: The error is on line 109 of the file `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`. If you are looking for a syntax error, you should look around there.

Comment: @richard-smith - Thanks a ton, that was the issue!